# ThreeJS: Using a Sprite with the OculusRiftEffect

Tags: javascript, three.js, oculus, webvr

I'm developing for the OculusRift using the OculusRiftEffect from https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/effects/OculusRiftEffect.js and am using Sprites. The problem is the sprites don't appear in the correct position in each eye as in the screenshot.[image: screenshot] You can see the house sprite is in different positions in each eye and causes a 'double vision' effect in the oculus. While playing around with the code (have a demo plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/oQPptIQBwKvsx12qpbcj?p=preview)) you can notice that near the edges of the screen the positioning is more accurate but I need it nearer the center of the screen where the positioning is off. I assume this has something to do with the shading/rendering in OculusRiftEffect but don't know enough about it to break it down, any direction would be appreciated, thanks!

**Sample code:**

```
var _scene, _camera, _renderer, _effect, _sprite;

function init() {
  _scene = new THREE.Scene();
  _camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, .1, 100000);
  _camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3());
  _renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true,
      canvas: document.getElementById('legit')
    });

  _renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  _effect = new THREE.OculusRiftEffect(_renderer, {
    worldScale: 1000
  });
  _effect.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

  _sprite = new THREE.Sprite(
    new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
        map: new THREE.Texture(document.getElementById('icon')),
        color: 0xff0000
    })
  );

  _sprite.scale.set(200, 200, 1);
  _sprite.position.set(500, 800, 1);
  _scene.add(_sprite);

  _scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereGeometry(3000, 64, 32),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xffffff,
      wireframe: true,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide
    })
  ));

  animate();
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

function render() {
    _renderer.render(_scene, _camera);
    _effect.render(_scene, _camera);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```

Comment: Not quite sure what is going on here. What is the photo in the background? How are you matching these two, are you sure that your house sprite is sitting exactly where it should be compared to the real world (photo)? 

"Different positions in each eye" is somewhat relative. World space, yes it should be the same, screenspace/camera space, it should be different.

Comment: the photo in the background is an image projected onto a sphere and the house is a sprite so its positioning is set relative to the camera view. im not trying to match them, rather the house icon is supposed to be a HuD type thing. in the demo i linked to i used a wireframe so you could see the effect. the way i understand it is since these are sprites they should be in the same spot relative to the world no matter the camera angle...even if they should be in different spots they are offset by far too much

Comment: Could you try positioning your sprite to be as close to the camera as possible? If your near is one, make it sit at 1.0001 from the camera.

Comment: well here's what i mean about the positioning: changing the x and y move it laterally and longitudinally around the screen from the camera's perspective but changing the z doenst affect it all (ive tried the same as the camera's near, negative values, the camera's far, etc...)

Comment: Can you post some code or a working demo, i don't see any of that movement in the link above.

Comment: I'm confused by the sphere at 3000 radius, and then your sprite sitting at 500,800.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/oQPptIQBwKvsx12qpbcj?p=preview thats my demo...the sizes are not particular just what im using in the actual code. changing the sizes doesnt affect the behavior though

Comment: *edit* i had to resize the window to actually see the sprite (you could have made it red, not black on black :)

Comment: I think this is due to the way the sprite gets projected. You were actually doing it correctly, it was not in world space, but it's acting like it is slightly. Unfortunately i don't have access to the Rift but I assume that an element like this should be aligned the same on both sides to be in focus? Without studying the oculusrift.js it's hard to tell what's going on. It seems that the same camera has it's world matrix changed to create the paralax for the left and right eye. The sprite has an unusual projection as well which is probably projecting it for the original pos, not each eye.

Comment: You have two of these - "this.preLeftRender, this.preRightRender", perhaps you can try putting your sprite in world space, linking it to the camera, and then apply the same transformation that gets applied to the camera. This way you would do everything manually in JS rather than the shader, but at least it could work. The idea is to have two sprites rendered almost at camera's near, they never change relative to their eye, and they are visible only when their eye renders the scene. I think that with a sprite, you'll only need to worry about the position, not alignment.

Comment: yeah, thats what the issue seems like to me (sorry about the color, i threw that together after a LOT of debugging). i saw preLeft and preRight render but was hoping i could avoid digging into that custom rendering code, oh well...

Comment: It does not need to be super complicated, you probably don't need to write any shaders either, just kinda 'hack' the position. Why don't you try putting really tiny sprites to the camera, at the same distance apart. Worse case scenario, you might have them both appear on one but at least youll see if its aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pailhead and Jherico mentioned this is not possible with the Oculus plugin. A workaround I found effective is to simply use a PlaneGeometry and set it as a child of the camera. Set it to look at the camera's position and it will act just like a sprite and render correctly for the OculusRiftEffect. Basic example (assuming camera and scene):

```
var sprite = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff})
);
//assuming camera is at (0,0,0) we need to offset it
sprite.position.set(20, 20, -100);
sprite.lookAt(camera.position);

camera.add(sprite);

//normally camera doesnt need to be added
//but if it has child meshes it is necessary
scene.add(camera);
```

Since the plane is a child of the camera once its offset is positioned correctly it will follow the camera wherever it goes. The caveat is that it won't function exactly the same as a Sprite in that you can't move it independently around the scene but it's the closest solution I've found.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with the Oculus plugin but I think your understanding of how sprites work is wrong.

Sprite is a rendering technique - a renderable rasterized surface... It can still be anywhere in space, and space is a relative term.

Is your house aware that it's part of the HUD and not part of a particle system somewhere in the distance?

One way to achieve what you want would be to overlay a copy at equal distance from the two points that represent the center of each eye, all in screen space. I think that this would give the effect that you are looking for.

That's as far as the positioning goes. Orientation wise, i'm not sure if they are actually properly aligned in your image above but the fish-eye effect is kicking in.

Answer (score 0):

My reading of Three.js sprites indicates that they are positioned using screen coordinates, not in-scene geometry.  Because of this they're ignoring the per-eye projection matrix offset that is imposed on the scene. I don't believe they will function properly in combination with the Oculus Rift distortion effect because of this.

Comment: do you think the oculus effect can be modified to accommodate them?